# find prior instance attachments for ebs volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to clean up some old AWS accounts to reduce costs, and need to get rid of unnecessary EBS volumes that are not attached to anything.

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids "blah" "blah"
```

does return a list of volumes, but doesn't provide info on which VM it might have been attached to.

Before I delete a whole bunch and we lose data that might be needed, I was wondering if there is a good approach to get that info?

Looked into cross referencing with Snapshot Id's and seeing what was there, but almost all have been deleted. Only one volume so far has tags that describe the old VM.

Comment: I think tagging would normally be the best approach here but that's no help if you failed to tag the volumes. If you have CloudTrail logs enabled then you might be able to pull those logs down and search for AttachVolume calls that map EBS volume IDs to EC2 instance IDs.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. I know what we will be changing as policy moving forward.

Comment: EBS volumes can be detached from one instance and attached to another at any time so I'd be surprised if there were any metadata stored with the EBS volume that indicated which instance(s) it had historically been attached to.

Comment: Cloud trail logs might help